# Matching JSON with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, python, json, regex

I have a JavaScript file containing many object literals:

```
// lots of irrelevant code
oneParticularFunction({
    key1: "string value",
    key2: 12345,
    key3: "strings which may contain ({ arbitrary characters })"
});
// more irrelevant code
```

I need to write some Python code to extract these literals.

My first attempt was a regular expression `oneParticularFunction\(\{(.*?)\}\);`. But this fails if the literal contains a "})".

Since I know the objects will be valid JSON (matched quotes, braces, etc) in a valid JavaScript file, is there a more elegant way to extract them?

(In other words, the difficulty is removing all the other JavaScript code I don't care about.)

EDIT: In the end, I used a regular expression for any objects which don't contain sub-objects...

```
oneParticularFunction\((\{([^"}]*"[^"]*"[^"}]*)*?[^"]*?\})\);
```

...and tracked open/close braces by hand for anything with nesting.

Comment: how about using one of the json decoder in python? and then you iterate each key-value pairs.

Comment: @elfan I am hoping to use `json`, but I need to get rid of all the surrounding JavaScript first.

Comment: If the code looks like your example, you could implement a Python version of the `oneParticularFunction()` JavaScript function and then try to execute the code fragment (which is just a function call) from the file with `eval`. If it succeeds, then you can extract the values from the argument the function was passed (which will be a Python dictionary object).

Comment: @martineau That is a beautiful hack, but unfortunately Python insists on quotes around dictionary keys, while JSON does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not writing a state machine that reads { and increments a counter on every { and decrements it with every } so when it reaches 0 again, take all the characters in the middle and use the json parser from python to check if it is valid or not? on that way, you can get the benefit of syntactical errors instead of a simple match no match from the regex (remember python is { free so false positives are impossible).

Comment: That's definitely a good option; I'm just hoping there's some more Pythonic way that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I've done python for few years... I'd say it is a good bet but wait a bit to see if we get a better answer.

Comment: A state-machine approach would also have to be able to handle strings within the JavaScript literal which theoretically could themselves contain `{` and `}` characters. What do you mean Python is free from those characters? It's common way to define literal dictionaries in Python code.

Comment: I mean they are not used for flow control

Answer (score 2):

Regex code:

```
(?<=(?:\s\"))[\s\S]+?(?=\")|(?<=(?:\s))\d+
```

Live example of regex at https://regex101.com/r/bfNkvF/3

To use the previous regex in Python:

```
import re
text = '''oneParticularFunction({
key1: "string value",
key2: 12345,
key3: "strings which may contain ({ arbitrary characters })"
});'''
for m in re.finditer(r"(?<=(:\s\"))[\s\S]+?(?=\")|(?<=(:\s))\d+", text):
    print('%s' % (m.group(0)))
```

I tested this code on [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit), and it seems to work. You can copy it and paste it there. Let me know if it works on the other object literals.

Comment: This works wonderfully once I have a particular instance extracted, though if there are other function calls or multiple calls to oneParticularFunction it seems to combine them all together. But now that I've been introduced to lookahead and lookbehind I think that's going to be the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this to remove all brackets from a string without eliminating or mismatching an outer '({' and '})'

```
while True:
    newstring = re.sub(r'(\(\{.*)\{([^{}]*)\}(.*\}\))', r'\1\2\3', mystring)
    if newstring == mystring:
        break
    mystring = newstring
```

There are 3 groups here (I know, it's hard to tell). The first is `(\(\{.*)`. This finds your `({` and then whatever comes after it up until it finds the inner most `{`

We know it is the inner most `{` because of the second group `([^{}]*)`. This will match anything that is not a `{` or `}`.

Then, `(.*\}\))` finds everything after the innermost `}`.

This whole match is replaced by combining these three groups back together (with the `{}`'s left out). It repeats this until it finds no more matching braces to replace.

If you wanted to also replace `()`'s, you could modify it to

```
newstring = re.sub(r'(\(\{.*)(\{|\()([^{}()]*)(\}|\))(.*\}\))', r'\1\3\5', mystring)
```