# Python Regex that will work for any type of bracket

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to take a regular expression, such as

```
\(.*\)
```

and make it correctly identify pairs of any type of bracket, like

```
(\(|\{|\[).*(\)|\}|\])
```

without making incorrect matches, like `\(.*\]`?

I'm specifically working with Python, but it should work similarly in any language.

Comment: Something like `\(.*?\)|{.*?}|\[.*?]` should be enough in the majority of cases, with or without `re.S` flag.

Comment: Do you have to take care of nested brackets too?

Comment: @Sebastian Proske ideally yes, I gave a simple example for illustration, but I hope to use this for general application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Regular languages can't handle nesting correctly. You'll need a proper parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic way to tell regex to match a specific char to some other char (if it was the exact same char/string you could do a backreference look, but this is not the case).

What you can do is write a "complex" (not so much) expression for that:

```
((?:\(.*\))|(?:\{.*\})|(?:\[.*\]))
```

Comment: Well sure, but that gets very unwieldy very quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:\([^()]*\))|(?:\{[^{}]*\})|(?:\[[^[\]]*\]))
```

Even more unwieldy, but unlike the solution containing `.*` this will only catch the innermost pair of brackets in case of nested brackets. Between a pair of brackets everything is allowed, even newlines, except the brackets themselves `[^{}]`.

`.*` is greedy, it would catch two pairs of brackets as one group, like *(ab)cd(ef)*, or even mix pairs chaotically and match *(ab)cd)* for example.

To catch a group containing the *outer* pair of brackets like *(ab(cd)ef)* I would consider not possible with regex.

Comment: Yeah, my question was actually inspired after I gave an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456091/matching-json-with-a-regular-expression/40513632#40513632